# Scrapy - Submitting form with scraped results of other website

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the website themoviedb.org with movies I scraped on another tv-guide website. The idea behind it is to get movie information (rating, release date, ...) on movies that will be shown in the coming days.

So I scrape the movie title from the first website and want to get extra info by using the search form on themoviedb.org.

```
    def parse(self, response):
    for col_inner in response.xpath('//div[@class="grid__col__inner"]'):
        chnl = col_inner.xpath('.//div[@class="tv-guide__channel"]/h6/a/text()').extract()
        for program in col_inner.xpath('.//div[@class="program"]'):
            item = TVGuideItem()
            item['channel'] = chnl
            title = program.xpath('.//div[@class="title"]/a/text()').extract()
            title = unidecode.unidecode(title[0])  # Replace special characters with characters without accents, ...
            title = urllib.quote_plus(title)  # Create valid url parameter
            item['title'] = list(title)
            item['start_ts'] = program.xpath('.//div[@class="time"]/text()').extract()

            # Extract information from the Movie Database www.themoviedb.org
            request = scrapy.FormRequest(url="https://www.themoviedb.org/", formdata={'query': title]}, callback=self.parse_tmdb)

            request.meta['item'] = item  # Pass the item with the request to the detail page

            yield request


def parse_tmdb(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']  # Use the passed item
    film = response.xpath('//div[@class="item poster card"][1]')
    item['genre'] = film.xpath('.//span[class="genres"]/text()').extract()
    item['plot'] = film.xpath('.//p[class="overview"]/text()').extract()
    item['rating'] = film.xpath('//span[class="vote_average"]/text()').extract()
    item['release_date'] = film.xpath('.//span[class="release_date"]/text()').extract()

    return item
```

But I get the error Ignoring response <404 https://www.themoviedb.org/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed. So I have no idea how to solve this.

**EDIT: I changed the code a bit to remove special characters from the title with unidecode and replace blanks with the plus sign. I am now also passing a string in the formdata of the FormRequest. But I keep getting the same DEBUG warning and nothing is scraped from themoviedb.org.**

I also added the log:

```
2015-10-27 21:09:39 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: topfilms)
2015-10-27 21:09:39 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-10-27 21:09:39 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'topfilms.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['topfilms.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'topfilms'}
2015-10-27 21:09:39 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-10-27 21:09:39 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-10-27 21:09:39 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-10-27 21:09:39 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: StoreInDBPipeline
2015-10-27 21:09:39 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-10-27 21:09:39 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-27 21:09:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-10-27 21:09:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.nieuwsblad.be/tv-gids/vandaag/film> from <GET http://www.nieuwsblad.be/tv-gids/vandaag/film/>
2015-10-27 21:09:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.nieuwsblad.be/tv-gids/vandaag/film> (referer: None)
2015-10-27 21:09:40 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <POST https://www.themoviedb.org/> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2015-10-27 21:09:40 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <POST https://www.themoviedb.org/> (referer: http://www.nieuwsblad.be/tv-gids/vandaag/film)
2015-10-27 21:09:40 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <POST https://www.themoviedb.org/> (referer: http://www.nieuwsblad.be/tv-gids/vandaag/film)

<... SAME MESSAGE REPEATED MULTIPLE TIMES ...>

2015-10-27 21:09:41 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <404 https://www.themoviedb.org/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2015-10-27 21:09:41 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-10-27 21:09:41 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 34287,
 'downloader/request_count': 79,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 77,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 427844,
 'downloader/response_count': 79,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 77,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 27, 20, 9, 41, 943855),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 158,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 78,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 79,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 79,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 79,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 79,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 27, 20, 9, 39, 502545)}
2015-10-27 21:09:41 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first Selector xpaths return a list, so what you have in `item['title']` is a list, which you are passing into `formdata={'query': item['title']}` is that.

Now, if you still need to parse unhandled status (like still being able to parse a respone with 400 status), you should use the errback parameter in the request, something like this:

```
...
    yield scrapy.FormRequest(url="https://www.themoviedb.org/", 
                             formdata={'query': item['title']},
                             callback=self.parse_tmdb,
                             errback=self.parse_error,
                             meta = {'item': item})
def parse_error(self, response):
    # do your magic
    ...
...
```